# JBehave scenario meta parameters in 4.0

Tags: jbehave

I recently upgraded from JBehave 3.10 to 4.0.4.  This upgrade has broken my scenario based meta data.  I use meta data properties on some of my scenarios which is passed into steps via named parameters.  However, now the actual meta value passed into the step seems to randomly be any of the values assigned to any of the scenarios in the same story.  I'll provide an example of what I'm doing to provide more context.

```
Meta:
@set Smoke

Narrative:
When I do something......

Scenario: Scenario 1
Meta:
@brand One
Given ...
When ...
Then ...

Scenario: Scenario 2
Meta:
@brand Two
Given ...
When ...
Then ...


@Given(...)
public void scenarioStep(@Named("brand") String brand, @Named("url") String url) {
// Do something with brand
}
```

In the example above, when scenarioStep is called for Scenario 1 then it will sometimes pass a brand of "One" and sometimes "Two", when it should always be "one".

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening here?  I have tried changing the Jbehave-Core to older versions of the 4.0 releases, but they all exhibit the same behavior.  When I switch back to 3.10 then it works fine again.

Comment: Also, what do your steps look like when you execute them? Typically the named parameters map to the $ delimited arguments in the step pattern so one would have something like @Given a brand name $brand with a hosturl $url

Comment: There is an example step at the bottom of my example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some extensive debugging into the JBehave framework I think I have found the problem.  before executing a story, it is first converted into a PerformableStory and the scenarios into PerformableScenarios.  During that process the available named parameters (from the metadata) are passed around as a hash map and stored with the PerformableScenario.  However in the JBehave 4.x code it is the same hash map being used and updated in each scenario in the story.

Since each scenario is sharing the same named parameter map, then the last scenario to be parsed will overwrite the scenario level metadata parameters for all the other ones in that story.  The hash map needs to be copied for each scenario.

I have forked the project and patched the code to do this.  This has fixed the issues that I was seeing.  I am going to see if I can manage to open a bug for this on the JBehave project.

Update: I have opened bug JBEHAVE-1129 for this issue on the JBehave project.

Comment: It looks like the fix has been incorporated into the upcoming 4.0.5 release.

Answer (score 1):

jBehave will load your entire testing suite before parsing it using the specified grammar found [here](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/grammar.html). If the compiled tests don't meet the expected grammar (e.g. out of place keywords etc.) it causes jBehave to have seemingly sporadic behavior.

One way to test that your jBehave tests are kosher is to print out the textual representation of your scenarios after it is loaded, but before executing and matching it against the grammar. In the above example I can see that the narrative 'When' keyword isnt supported.

```java
; The narrative is identified by keyword "Narrative:" (or equivalent in I18n-ed locale),
; It is followed by the narrative elements
Narrative:= "Narrative:" ( InOrderTo AsA IWantTo | AsA IWantTo SoThat ) ;

; The narrative elements
InOrderTo:= "In order to" NarrativeElementContent ;
AsA:= "As a" NarrativeElementContent ;
IWantTo:= "I want to" NarrativeElementContent ;
SoThat:= "So that" NarrativeElementContent ;

; The narrative starting words (or equivalent in I18n-ed locale)
NarrativeStartingWord :== ("In order to" | "As a" | "I want to" | "So that") ;
```

I can't find the grammar files to diff between the versions but the grammar update history is found [here](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/commits/8dc5e6ced617a05b7400d92a3ccaff7541c060d9/jbehave-core/src/main/java/org/jbehave/core/parsers/grammar.ebnf). It looks like it's very probable there were changes between jBehave revisions to the grammar.

**Edit:** 
For printing out the steps / components before executing add the [default console reporter](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/reporting-stories.html) e.g.

```java
new StoryReporterBuilder()
        .withFailureTrace(true)
        .withFormats(CONSOLE, TXT, HTML, XML)
);
```

Please post your out, or any inconsistencies in the log to further debug

Comment: The error in the narrative is my fault when I put in the example here.  I have been out of the office, so haven't followed up on your suggestion yet.  I'll do as you suggest and see what turns up.

Comment: I have checked out the parsing of the narrative and the scenarios.  Everything checks out.  I'm doing some debugging to try and learn more.